# Symfony2 change validation group based on field value

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have controller action like this:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new Client();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new ClientType(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('client_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

The underlying `Client` Entity has a field `type` witch can take values `[0, 1]` now, I have defined the 2 validation groups for `Client` entity: `person` and `company`.

How can I change/choose validation group based on user entered value into `type` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a callback validation constraint for your class (Client entity), from the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html):

> Classes
>
> Some constraints apply to the entire class being validated. For example, the [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/Callback.html) constraint is a generic constraint that's applied to the class itself. When that class is validated, methods specified by that constraint are simply executed so that each can provide more custom validation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, I use callback validators very often but I can't see how I can "link" them with validation groups, can you show me any example?

Comment: Manually: `$errors = $validator->validate($client, array('registration'));`, the other option I see if you can specify it for the forms `getDefaultOptions` function returning the appropriate registration group based on `$client`.

Comment: Yeah I think validation groups are not really intended for your purpose, maybe to have two entity classes that share a base class is better or so. No idea ;)